# C application hangs after writing data to a pipe. How to check if "cat" process is done?

Tags: c, pipe, buffer, fork, exec

My C application I want to write data to a piped process. Next, I want to have a file descriptor in which all the written data is buffered. For this, I chose to use the cat command. The following is my code (an oversimplified version of the problem, that is):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PIPE_READ 0
#define PIPE_WRITE 1

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int fd[2];
    int childpid;
    int writePntr;
    pipe(fd);
    if ((childpid = fork()) == -1) {
        perror("fork");
    }
    if (childpid == 0) {
        dup2(fd[PIPE_WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO); // send stdout to the pipe
        char a = 'a';
        write(fd[PIPE_WRITE], &a, 1);
        char b = 'b';
        write(fd[PIPE_WRITE], &b, 1);
        write(fd[PIPE_WRITE], '\0', 1);
        close(fd[PIPE_WRITE]);
        close(fd[PIPE_READ]);
        char *cmd = "cat";
        char *argv[2];
        argv[0] = "cat";
        argv[1] = NULL;

        execvp(cmd, argv);
        exit(1);
    } else {
        close(fd[PIPE_WRITE]);
        writePntr = fd[PIPE_READ];
    }
    wait(NULL);
    char readbuffer[1];
    while (read(writePntr, readbuffer, 1) > 0) {
        printf(readbuffer);
    }
    close(writePntr);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The problem with this code, is that it hangs on both the `wait(&childpid);` and the `while (read(writePntr, readbuffer, 1) > 0) {` (if I'd remove the wait statement). It literally seems to loop forever in that while loop, meaning the process never ends for some reason.

In this oversimplified version of my code I write the chars 'a' and 'b' to the pipe, followed by a NULL terminator (although I'm not sure if that is required). I believe I close all necessary sides of the pipe. In the real version of the code, the 'a' and 'b' are actually complete buffers being written to the pipe. The reason I have to do this, in that I want to have **a single file descriptor** that contains all data of another file descriptor appended to all the data of yet another file descriptor.

Does anyone know why the attached code hangs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code, I tried to explain in comments.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        int fd[2];
        int childpid;
        int writePntr;
        pipe(fd);
        if ((childpid = fork()) == -1) {
                perror("fork");
        }
        if (childpid == 0) {
                dup2(fd[PIPE_WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO); // send stdout to the pipe
                char a = 'a';
                write(fd[PIPE_WRITE], &a, 1);
                char b = 'b';
                write(fd[PIPE_WRITE], &b, 1);
                write(fd[PIPE_WRITE], '\0', 1);
                dup2(3,0);
                dup2(4,1); /* you must duplicate pipe[1] to stdout */
                char *cmd = "/bin/cat";
                char *argv[2];
                argv[0] = "cat";
                argv[1] = "data";/* data is the file name */
                execlp(cmd, argv[0],argv[1],NULL);
                perror("execvp");

                exit(1);
        } else {
                close(fd[PIPE_WRITE]);
                writePntr = fd[PIPE_READ];
        }
        wait(NULL);
        char readbuffer; /* take only char */
        while (read(writePntr, &readbuffer, 1) > 0) {/* read char by char */
                printf("%c \n",readbuffer);
        }
        close(writePntr);
        return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: This works, but why do we need to specify a file name? When I do `echo hello | cat` in the linux terminal, the output is `hello` and the process exits. No need to specify a file name there.

Comment: Replacing `"data"` with `"/dev/null"` seems to work for my purposes :)
Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Check the man page for [`wait(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) -- it probably isn't doing what you think it's supposed to do, which is to wait until a child process that you created terminates.

Also, the parameter is where the status of the terminated process is written, not the PID of the process you're waiting on -- that would be `waitpid`, which is related.

Note that you're calling `wait` for both the child and the parent - so the child is waiting for its child to die before dying, and notifying its parent.

Comment: You say the child is waiting for its child to die before dying, and notifying its parent. The child should've exited by then because of the `exit(1);` statement right?

Comment: I've read the man page `man 2 wait`, it should wait till the child process reaches an `exit` statement right? I should indeed use `waitpid`, but in this example that doesn't change anything right?

Comment: Even if I remove the `wait` call and move the `readbuffer` reading to the `else` clause it yields the same result.